# How to read files in Chrome devtools Sources tab programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I do this manually a lot so I want to automate the process. Basically I always have to open up Chrome DevTools, go to Sources tab, then find the file I'm looking for and copy a particular value from it.

Is there any way to do this using code? I'm trying to retrieve a value from external sources loaded by the website.

Comment: Is the value in text of `<script>`, or `<link>` element?

Comment: The value is in the file `src` loaded by `<script>`

Comment: What is the value you are trying to retrieve?

Comment: One idea. You could write a Chrome Extension to intercept requests to a certain URL pattern using WebRequest API. You cannot currently read or modify the response body, but you can cancel the original request and make a new Ajax request. You can then get the response body, pass it through a parsing function to extract the data you want and log it to the console.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer for sure without knowing what type of value you're trying to retrieve, but how about a [snippet](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/snippets)?